# Parsing ember-leaflet coordinates from json using ember models

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, ember.js, leaflet

I am new to `ember` and `ember-leaflet.js`. I am trying to feed data (via an `ajax` call to a `json` file) to both my handlebars template and my ember-leaflet map. With my current setup, the data reaches my handlebars template just fine, but doesn't render the coordinates data to the ember-leaflet map.

I am using the two examples listed below as my guides, but have hit a wall because of my lack of experience with ember. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

[Ajax and ember example](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-into-emberjs-part-3--net-31394)

[Partial example of what I'm trying to accomplish](https://github.com/gabesmed/ember-leaflet/issues/28)

Handlebars template:

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    {{outlet}}

  </script>

   <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
      {{view App.MapView id="map"}}
      <div id="blog">
        <ul>
            {{#each item in model}}
                <li>{{item.headline}}</li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>    
    </div>  
  </script>
```

Ember:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return App.Item.all();
    }
});

App.Item = Ember.Object.extend();

App.Item.reopenClass({
  all: function() {
      return $.getJSON("js/data/test_e.json").then(function(response) {
        var items = [];

        response.features.forEach( function (data) {
          items.push( App.Item.create(data) );
        });

          return items;
      });
  }
});

App.MarkerCollectionLayer =
  EmberLeaflet.MarkerCollectionLayer.extend({
    locationBinding: 'controller.item.center'});

App.MapView = EmberLeaflet.MapView.extend({
    childLayers: [
      EmberLeaflet.DefaultTileLayer,
      App.MarkerCollectionLayer]
});

App.IndexController =
  Ember.Controller.extend({});
```

JSON file:

```
{
    "features": [
        {
            "headline": "Docker, the Linux container runtime: now open-source",
            "center" : [40.714, -74.000]
        },
        {
            "headline": "What's Actually Wrong with Yahoo's Purchase of Summly",
            "center" : [40.714, -73.989]

        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main fix needed here is the `locationBinding` in the MarkerCollectionLayer. The `location` binding needs to be in the MarkerLayer class. Furthermore, you need to use the `EmberLeaflet.computed` functions to convert simple lat lng arrays to a Leaflet LatLng object. See this example:

```
App.MarkerCollectionLayer = EmberLeaflet.MarkerCollectionLayer.extend({
  content: Ember.computed.alias('controller'),
  itemLayerClass: EmberLeaflet.MarkerLayer.extend({
    location: EmberLeaflet.computed.latLngFromLatLngArray('content.center'),
  })
});
```

Check out this JSFiddle with a full working example: http://jsfiddle.net/xALu4/2/

Comment: However this is a great item to consider fixing on EmberLeaflet's end -- it should handle lat lng arrays correctly by default. I've added it to our issues list!